# Is there a way to get case-sensitive collation for utf8 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

I have a mysql table of IPA pronunciation syllables, and I'd like to have case sensitivity on a unique key, a varchar containing lots of characters with accent marks.  I'd also like characters with different accents to be treated as unequal.

I checked out 
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?580030-case-sensitive-unicode-table, and while I think it would solve my uniqueness issues, I'd prefer not to have strange ordering caused by utf8_bin.

I only need to programmatically access the db through java via hibernate, so I was thinking I could change the unique key to be a unique key on the syllable varchar and an integer (the java.lang.String or some custom hash of the string), but this leaves a tiny possibility of collisions.

I'd be willing to work on creating my own custom collation for this use case if it's not too much work.  What would be a good alternative to utf8_bin collation?  Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [choose a collation on a per-query, per-clause basis](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collate.html), the collation chosen when creating the table is simply the default. So you can use the `bin` collation for comparison and another one for ordering.

Comment: another [source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) with same technique